# Can inside the same function startActivity(intent), then after getting value from the startActivity, run getintent() to get the value?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

It has been getting error unable to resume activity and null pointer exception. However i try putting this Intent intents = getIntent(); String cats = intents.getStringExtra("Final_Weight"); after super.oncreate and print it out, i'm able to get the value. But when i use getIntent() to get the value, i'm unable to get it. How should i get the value? Below is how i sent the value.

```
  String search = Final_Weight;
    Intent intent = new 
  Intent(activity.getApplication(),ShoppingCartActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Final_Weight", search);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

This class is how i get the value being sent to me. I'm putting the value in a variable call shippingfee.

```
public class ShoppingCartActivity extends Activity{
public List<ContactObjects> mCartList = new ArrayList<>();
public ProductAdapter mProductAdapter;
private static Map<ContactObjects, ShoppingCartEntry> cartMap = new 
HashMap<ContactObjects, ShoppingCartEntry>();
public static ListView listViewCatalog;
public static final String WEIGHT = "username";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart);
    HomeActivity1.emptyCart = true;
    HomeActivity1.emptyCount = true;
  mCartList = ShoppingCartActivity.getCartList();


    // Make sure to clear the selections
    for(int i=0; i<mCartList.size(); i++) {
        mCartList.get(i).selected = false;
    }
    System.out.println("This is it" + mCartList);
    System.out.println("This is all" + cartMap.keySet().size());

    // Create the list
    listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
    mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mCartList, getLayoutInflater(), 
  true, true, true);
    listViewCatalog.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

    listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
  position,
                                long id) {

            ContactObjects selectedProduct = mCartList.get(position);
            if (selectedProduct.selected == true)
                selectedProduct.selected = false;
            else
                selectedProduct.selected = true;

            mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }
    });

    Button removeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
    removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i;
            // Loop through and remove all the products that are selected
            // Loop backwards so that the remove works correctly

            for (i = mCartList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {


                if (mCartList.get(i).selected) {
                    mCartList.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("This is all" + mCartList);
                }
            }
            mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            String value = "0.00";
            String values;
            double totalweight = 0;
            double shippingfee = 0;
            for(ContactObjects p : mCartList) {
                int quantity = ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(p);
                try {
                    double weights = Double.parseDouble(p.weight);
                    totalweight += weights * quantity;
                    String weigh = String.valueOf(totalweight);
                    Intent intent = new 
    Intent(ShoppingCartActivity.this,shopping1.class);
                    intent.putExtra(WEIGHT, weigh);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Intent intents = getIntent();
                    String cats = intents.getStringExtra("Final_Weight");

                    double final_price = Double.parseDouble(cats);
                    shippingfee = final_price;
                    shippingfee = Shopping.getShipping(totalweight);
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
                value = String.format("%.2f", shippingfee);
            }

            double subTotal = 0;
            for(ContactObjects p : mCartList) {
                int quantity = ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(p);
                try {
                    double prices = Double.parseDouble(p.price);
                    subTotal += prices * quantity;
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
                values = String.format("%.2f", subTotal);
            }
            if (subTotal >= 150){
                shippingfee = 0;
                subTotal += shippingfee;
                values = String.format("%.2f", subTotal);
            }
            else{
                for(ContactObjects p : mCartList) {
                    int quantity = 
    ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(p);
                    try {
                        double weights = Double.parseDouble(p.weight);
                        totalweight += weights * quantity;
                        String weigh = String.valueOf(totalweight);
                        Intent intent = new 
    Intent(ShoppingCartActivity.this,shopping1.class);
                        intent.putExtra(WEIGHT, weigh);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Intent intents = getIntent();
                        String cats = 
     intents.getStringExtra("Final_Weight");

                        double final_price = Double.parseDouble(cats);
                        shippingfee = final_price;
                       shippingfee = Shopping.getShipping(totalweight);
                    }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
                    value = String.format("%.2f", shippingfee);
                }
                subTotal += shippingfee;
                values = String.format("%.2f", subTotal);
            }
            TextView productPriceTextView = (TextView) 
  findViewById(R.id.TextViewSubtotal);
            productPriceTextView.setText("Subtotal: RM" + values);
            TextView productWeightTextView = (TextView) 
    findViewById(R.id.TextViewSubweight);
            productWeightTextView.setText("Shipping Weight: " + totalweight 
  +" kg");
            TextView productShippingTextView = (TextView)
   findViewById(R.id.TextViewShipping);
            productShippingTextView.setText("Shipping Fee: RM" + value);

        }
    });

    Button btnHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
    btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
   /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity abd Start The Activity
            Intent intentSignUP = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),   
   HomeActivity1.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
        }
    });

    Button btnCheckout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    btnCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
  /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity abd Start The Activity
            Intent intentSignUP = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
  ShippingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
        }
    });
}

public static void setQuantity(ContactObjects product, int quantity, double
 weight) {
    // Get the current cart entry
    ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

    // If the quantity is zero or less, remove the products
    if(quantity <= 0) {
        if(curEntry != null)
            removeProduct(product);
        return;
    }

    // If a current cart entry doesn't exist, create one
    if(curEntry == null) {
        curEntry = new ShoppingCartEntry(product, quantity, weight);
        cartMap.put(product, curEntry);
        return;
    }

    // Update the quantity
    curEntry.setQuantity(quantity);
}

public static int getProductQuantity(ContactObjects product) {
    // Get the current cart entry
    ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

    if(curEntry != null)
        return curEntry.getQuantity();

    return 0;
}


public static Map<ContactObjects, ShoppingCartEntry> getCartMap() {
    return cartMap;
}

public static void removeProduct(ContactObjects product) {
    cartMap.remove(product);
}

public static List<ContactObjects> getCartList() {
    List<ContactObjects> cartList = new Vector<>(cartMap.keySet().size());
    if (HomeActivity1.emptyCart == false) {
        for (ContactObjects p : cartMap.keySet()) {
            cartList.remove(p);
            cartMap.keySet().clear();
            cartList.clear();
            //ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.clear();
            ShoppingCartActivity.removeAll();
            System.out.println("This is all" + HomeActivity1.emptyCart);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (ContactObjects p : cartMap.keySet()) {
            cartList.add(p);
            System.out.println("This is what" + HomeActivity1.emptyCart);
        }
    }

    return cartList;
}
public static void removeAll(){
    cartMap.clear();
}
```

Comment: how should i put the string cats in shippingfee?

Comment: can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: get that in oncreate instead in button click

Comment: what do you mean by get it in oncreate?